# How to print the drupal username -without a link to it- inside the node profile?

Tags: users

So far the only thing that works is `$name` wich prints the username with the link.

I´ve tried `$account->name`, and it won´t print anything at all (I´ve tried `$author` and `$account_name;` too, without any luck).

I want to print the username inside their profile usernode in a Drupal 6 installation, but don´t want to print it with the link to it, just the username.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the exact answer you are looking for.
However I'd use `get_defined_vars()` in all template files to list the defined variables.

In case you are not a programmer, here's the code.

```
<pre>
<?php
  print_r(get_defined_vars());
?>
</pre>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Comment: Thanks for the input! (and specially thank you for the code, because yeah, I´m not a programmer :)